# Error while Installing apk on android raspberry pi3

Tags: android

my raspberry pi not x86.

when I install apk occur error.

`The currently selected variant "x86-debug" uses split APKs, 
but none of the 5 split apks are compatible with the current device with density
"213" and ABIs "armeabi-v7a, armeabi" Error while Installing APK`

so, I try modify gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my package name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'armeabi'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                 abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(''proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
    }
}
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```

but same error while installing apk.
I think, my android studio build type x86. but my raspberry pi type arm.
change my build type.

please advice for me

thanks.

Comment: Check the build output apks, just pick the right one to install, like app-arm.apk or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a new flavor arm:

```
arm {
      ndk {
         abiFilters ("armeabi","armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a")
      }
 }
```

should do the trick.